# Packaging the TCRM app template

Tags: managed-package, einstein-analytics, platform-bug, 2gp, tableau-crm

I'm currently working on a 2GP Managed Package that bundles Einstein Analytics (a.k.a. Tableau CRM) artifacts like `templates`, `dashboards`, `datasets`, `dataflows`.

For Map Chart I have **custom Map** in Einstein Analytics Dashboard.

This map is stored as `EclairGeoData` metadata.

But it seems that we cannot add `EclairGeoData` to 2GP since it is not supported by 2GP.

There is any way to add `EclairGeoData` to 2GP to add this Custom Map to the chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final answer here is that until salesforce adds the `EclairGeoData` to 2GP we cannot pack it.

To **workaround** it I used a standard map from salesforce and make **transformations** using **Dataflow**.

I have transformed every **two-character** country code into a **three-character** country code. This way it was presented in the right way.